# HTML tags in XML translation

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

How to add statements like the following one to translation (XLIFF format):

```
Click <a href='http://example.com'>here</a> to continue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you put it in a CDATA field within the xml?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Comment: This feels a tad hacky. Mixing content and markup like this is bad for maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

In Twig, you can include translation and disable autoescape, but you have to keep control of its content as it could be a security lack...

```
{% autoescape false %}{{ 'your.translation.id'|trans }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for this ! - cause |raw does not solve my problem